# c# winForm adding value to number in texbox

Tags: c#, winforms, button, textbox

In my program i have several texboxes and buttons with coresponding names (ex. TextBox1 - buttonPlus1) like on the picture

[image]

but there are filled with numbers loaded from text file.
I want to write function that allows me to press button + and enlarge (add fixed number, for example 100) value from textbox. So far i have done:

```
  private void buttonPlus1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddValue(sender,e);
    }

    private void AddValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(sender is Button))
            return;

        string controlName = (sender as Button).Name;
        string textBoxName = controlName.Replace("buttonPlus", "textBox");

        TextBox textBox = this.Controls.Find(textBoxName, false)[0] as TextBox;
        int step = 100;



    }
```

but i have no idea how to take value (as number) from textBox and add that step. Can somebody please help me? I tried to solve it by myself in many different ways, but it does not work

Comment: You can add a reference to the corresponding text box in the `.Tag` property of the button. Then your code would assign value with `(sender.Tag as TextBox).Value = ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the value:

```
Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text)
```

Save it to a variable, add 100 and just set it as usual.

P.S. You can also use `Int32.Parse("")`

```
textBox.Text = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text) + 100;
```

(You might need to `.ToString()` it)

EDIT:
As ltiong_sh mentioned, you should use TryParse rather then Parse:

```
int somevalue;
if(Int32.TryParse(textBox.Text, out somevalue))
{
    textBox.Text = somevalue + 100;
}
```

Comment: probably should use a Int32.TryParse()

Comment: ok,thanks for your help! it works with: <br/>   int newValue = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text) + step;<br/>
            textBox.Text = Convert.ToString(newValue);

Comment: @Juss I'm glad to hear. don't forget to accept as answer.

Itiong_sh - thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
int newValue = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text) + step;
```

To put the value back in a textbox you can do the following:

```
textBox.Text = newValue.ToString();
```

**Edit:**

As mentioned by others you should use Int32.TryParse to prevent an error from being thrown.

```
if(Int32.TryParse(textBox.Text, out newValue))
{
    newValue += step;
    textBox.Text = newValue.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ***convert String to Integer***

```
int txtValue = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text) + 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your validate the text in the text field. Else at the time of parsing it will throw an exception.

You can do this

```
int value = 0;
if(Int32.TryParse(textBox.Text, out value))
{
   value += step;
   textBox.Text = value.ToString();
}
else
{
   //inform user to enter int
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in button click get the textbox value and convert it to integer format and add 100 to it. after that reset textbox value to modified one's. Here is what you need.

```
private void buttonPlus1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
       int txtValue = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text) + 100;
       textBox.Text = txtValue.ToString();
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
   }
}
```